# Error: min(p, na.rm = TRUE) >= 0 is not TRUE

Tags: r

I came across an [interesting presentation](http://www.milanor.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/ROperationalRisk.201205.FabioPiacenza.pdf) on page 32, and I started out to replicate and understand a code presented

The code from the presentation is as follows:

```
#Unicredit banks code
library(evir)
library(fExtremes)
# Quantile function of lognormal-GPD severity distribution
qlnorm.gpd = function(p, theta, theta.gpd, u)
  {
    Fu = plnorm(u, meanlog=theta[1], sdlog=theta[2])
    x = ifelse(p<Fu,
               qlnorm( p=p, meanlog=theta[1], sdlog=theta[2] ),
               qgpd( p=(p - Fu) / (1 - Fu) , xi=theta.gpd[1], mu=theta.gpd[2], beta=theta.gpd[3]) )
  return(x)
  }
# Random sampling function of lognormal-GPD severity distribution

rlnorm.gpd = function(n, theta, theta.gpd, u)
  {
  r = qlnorm.gpd(runif(n), theta, theta.gpd, u)
  }

set.seed(1000)
nSim = 1000000 # Number of simulated annual losses
H = 1500 # Threshold body-tail
lambda = 791.7354 # Parameter of Poisson body
theta1 = 2.5 # Parameter mu of lognormal (body)
theta2 = 2 # Parameter sigma of lognormal (body)
theta1.tail = 0.5 # Shape parameter of GPD (tail)
theta2.tail = H # Location parameter of GPD (tail)
theta3.tail = 1000 # Scale parameter of GPD (tail)
sj = rep(0,nSim) # Annual loss distribution inizialization
freq = rpois(nSim, lambda) # Random sampling from Poisson
for(i in 1:nSim) # Convolution with Monte Carlo method
  sj[i] = sum(rlnorm.gpd(n=freq[i], theta=c(theta1,theta2), theta.gpd=c(theta1.tail, theta2.tail, theta3.tail), u=H))
```

However I get this error which I cannot resolve:

```
Error: min(p, na.rm = TRUE) >= 0 is not TRUE
```

### APPENDED Question

Many thanks to Shadow.

I dont know how to change function reference. Is it as easy as qgpd.fExtremes to qgpd.evir?

Thanks to Shadow again to pointing this out. 
For anyone who wishes to change reference to function from different package (In the above example from fExtremes to evir its as simple as adding evir:::(function).

Example:

```
evir:::qgpd( p=(p - Fu) / (1 - Fu) , xi=theta.gpd[1], mu=theta.gpd[2], beta=theta.gpd[3]) )
```

Comment: Are theta[1] or theta[2] ever less than zero? You are sending both as parameters that need to be positive.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get an error here is that the packages `fExtremes` and `evir` both implement different versions of the function `qgpd`. In the `evir` version, `p` can be less than 0, while the `fExtremes` package only implements `qgpd` for `p>=0`.

The easiest solution to this is to change the `qgpd` function call to `evir:::qgpd`.